# Google App engine Authentication Issue (google accounts API)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm am building a google app engine java based website.
I want to allow in only users who are logged in to google.
I chose Google Accounts API and went according to the instructions.
however when a user is not logged in with google it takes him to this silly log in page where he can chose (!) his google accounts email - not very secure.

[image: Login page generated by google app engine]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you were seeing is the mock login page from `Appengine sdk` on localhost which serves for testing purpose .. which just emulates google login . Unless until you deploy your application Your application can't use google login. After you deploy you will be taken to google's login page.

Comment: Yes, don't worry about it, when you deploy your users will see real Google Accounts authentication system. This is only a mock screen.

Comment: @Guy: If you needed Google account locally for development (which is probably unlikely, but I thought I'd mention), you could use something like RPX / Janrain Engage -- https://rpxnow.com/, but it would involve a fair bit more work than using Google accounts.